# ViewHolder: How to get context inside bind() function of Groupie RecyclerView Library?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm showing a List of users in my Firebase Database using the popular Groupie Library to generate the Recycler View. Inside the ViewHolder class's bind() [onBindViewHolder() without using Groupie], I'm trying to get the Dominant Color from the Palette created from the user's Profile Image & set that color as the Imageview's Shadow Color.

However, to use the palette, I need to provide context in the

> palette.getDominantColor(ContextCompat.getColor(**context**, R.color.defaultColor))

Problem is, how do I get this context inside the bind() function. If I try to pass the context in the function, it loses the Override & I get the error *'bind' overrides nothing.*

Here is my code to get better understanding of the problem.

```js
class FirebaseSearchActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

  //Get Firebase Database Reference
  private val dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase_search)

    val searchToolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.search_toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(searchToolbar)
    supportActionBar ? .setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

    getUserResults()
  }

  private fun getUserResults() {
    dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
      override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

        //Setup Groupie Adapter
        val adapter = GroupAdapter < ViewHolder > ()

        //Fetch Snapshot of Database
        p0.children.forEach {
          Log.d("FetchedUsers", "$it")
          //Assign Fetched Data to Model Class
          val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
          //Null Check
          if (user != null) {
            adapter.add(ResultItem(user, baseContext))
          }
        }

        //Attach Groupie Adapter to the Recycler View
        firebase_result_list.adapter = adapter
      }

      override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        //Show Error
        Log.d("FetchedUsers", "$p0")
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "$p0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }
    })
  }
}
//ViewHolder
class ResultItem(val user: User, ctx: Context): Item < ViewHolder > () {

  //Setup List Row Layout to View Holder
  override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.search_list_layout
  }

  //Change values of text fields or image views inside the list's layout
  override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    //Load Username
    Log.d("FetchedUserName", "Username: ${user.username}")
    viewHolder.itemView.search_list_username.text = user.username
    //Load Profile Pic
    Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
      .asBitmap()
      .load(user.profileImage)
      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
      .listener(object: RequestListener < Bitmap > {
        override fun onLoadFailed(
          e: GlideException ? ,
          model : Any ? ,
          target : com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target < Bitmap > ? ,
          isFirstResource : Boolean
        ): Boolean {
          return false
        }

        override fun onResourceReady(
          resource: Bitmap ? ,
          model : Any ? ,
          target : com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target < Bitmap > ? ,
          dataSource : DataSource ? ,
          isFirstResource : Boolean
        ): Boolean {
          if (resource != null) {
            val p = Palette.from(resource).generate()
            // Use generated instance
            viewHolder.itemView.search_list_profile.shadowColor = p.getDominantColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.defaultColor))
          }
          return false

        }
      })
      .into(viewHolder.itemView.search_list_profile)

  }
}
```

Comment: use `viewHolder.itemView.getContext()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your

`ctx:Context`

as this

`private val ctx:Context`

This way will able to access content in whole class.

Comment: Many thanks!! That worked. So a class variable is accessible throughout the entire class, even inside functions right? What a simple fix I couldn't think about. Oh well, good to know from others.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewHolder.itemView.context
```

This worked for me. I used it to create a child adapter inside my parent adapter for nested recycler views.